# showSoftInput doesn't work after orientation change

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad, android-input-method

I have a fragment with a single EditText that needs the soft keyboard to remain open continually.  The keyboard gets hidden when the screen is rotated.  I'm calling showSoftInput in OnActivityCreated which gets executed after the rotation, but it doesn't show the keyboard.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(edit, 0);
```

Note: I don't want to use toggleSoftInput.  I've tried that but it ends up closing the keyboard in some instances.  And there's no way to query android to determine if the keyboard is already open.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that showSoftInput is very buggy with Fragments.

First try @TronicZomB's solution.  It works for an Activity with a single Fragment.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

However, for an Activity with nested FragmentTransactions, you'll be forced to use toggleSoftInput with the SHOW_FORCED and HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS parameters.  HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS prevents the toggle command from closing the already opened keyboard after an orientation change.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

To hide the keyboard at a later time, you can use:

```
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the `InputMethodManager` with the following:

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I already do the following in onCreate:
getSherlockActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

Comment: Your method does work for a simple activity with a single fragment.  However, if the Activity has "transacted" to multiple fragments (Activity->AddFragment->ReplaceFragment), it no longer works.